# CGridView search not functioning when merged with create form

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have merged admin into create file by copying the gridview into create.php.

```
 <?php $this->renderPartial('_form', array('model'=>$model)); ?> 
<?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
        'id'=>'center-grid',
        'dataProvider'=>$model->search(),
        'filter'=>$model,
        'columns'=>array(
            'name',
            array(
                'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
            ),
        ),
    )); ?>
```

It is saving data but the search functionality of grid view is not functioning. Whereas, the same code of CGridView is functioning in admin.php.

here is my controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {
        $model=new Center;

        // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
        // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

        if(isset($_POST['Center']))
        {
            $model->attributes=$_POST['Center'];
            if($model->save())
                $this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$model->id));
        }

        $this->render('create',array(
            'model'=>$model,
        ));
    }
```

Comment: Could you include the controller method that renders this view?

Comment: @topher added the controller...

Answer (score 1):

After the model is saved you are redirecting to the same url i.e `create` but without the data from `$_POST`. The solution is to remove the call since you are essentially loading the same view, and would like to keep some of the data from the previous page.

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model=new Center;

    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed
    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);

    if(isset($_POST['Center']))
    {
        $model->attributes=$_POST['Center'];
        /*if($model->save())
            $this->redirect(array('create','id'=>$model->id));*/
    }

    $this->render('create',array(
        'model'=>$model,
    ));
}
```

**HOWEVER**

Reusing the same model for searching and inserting isn't a good approach since you will retain the data for the model that has been entered into the database (including its primary key(s)). A better one would be to use separate variables for the `search` and `create` and different `name` and `id` prefixes for fields of both forms. Then you can pass both variables into the views, and something entered into one field will not affect the other. You can also reuse the code in `actionAdmin` to refresh your grid via ajax without having to send the `create` form too.

Comment: Code implementation of your comment would really assist me understand your point, Thanks

Comment: Stack Overflow isn't a **give me code** site. First try the solution, and if your implementation doesn't work, ask another question. We will be happy to help, as long as you show effort.